# Login to Google Account using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, parsing, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to login to Google Acccount through HtmlUnit, but still something is wrong and I'm getting login page. What I'm doing wrong?

1. Set email
2. Click next button
3. Set password
4. Click login button
5. Go to GMail page and it's still login page (output below)

My example code:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        client.setHTMLParserListener(HTMLParserListener.LOG_REPORTER);
        client.setJavaScriptEngine(new JavaScriptEngine(client));
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        client.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        client.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
        client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

        String url = "https://accounts.google.com/login?hl=en#identifier";
        HtmlPage loginPage = client.getPage(url);
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000000);

        HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getFirstByXPath("//form[@id='gaia_loginform']");
        List<HtmlInput> buttonInputs = loginForm.getInputsByValue("signIn");
        HtmlInput nextButton = Iterables.getFirst(buttonInputs, null);
        HtmlInput loginButton = Iterables.getLast(buttonInputs);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //setup email
        HtmlInput emailInput = loginForm.getInputByName("Email");
        emailInput.setValueAttribute(emailAddress);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //click next button
        nextButton.click();
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000000);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //setup password
        HtmlInput passwordInput = loginForm.getInputByName("Passwd");
        passwordInput.setValueAttribute(password);

        //click login button
        loginButton.click();
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000000);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        HtmlPage gmailPage = client.getPage("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox");
        log.info(gmailPage.asText());
```

after all I'm getting output

```
2016-07-12 01:36:47 INFO  GoogleAccountClient:91 - Gmail

One account. All of Google.
 Sign in to continue to Gmail

 Next Need help?

Sign inchecked

Create account
 One Google Account for everything Google

About Google
 Privacy
 Terms
 Help

‪English (United States)‬

 identifier
```

I forgot something obvious?

I also tryied to click buttons by javascript

```
loginPage.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById('next').click()");
loginPage.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById('signIn').click()");
```

Comment: Well, it seems Google login triggers a lot of redirects. I suggest you print the current page URL to see where you are, and compare to your browser of choice in incognito mode. In fact, it is perfectly possible you are logged in Google. You could also try to navigate to an authenticated page (typically GMail) to see if you are forbidden or not.

Comment: Look at latest 2 lines 
`HtmlPage gmailPage = client.getPage("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox");`
`log.info(gmailPage.asText());`
I'm redirecting client after all to gmail page, and im getting output which is login page

Comment: @Jakub_Pomykała My bad. Have you tried using an HTTP proxy to see what HTTP requests are exchanged between HtmlUnit and Google ? Maybe you'll find some interesting differences with your browser during login initiation.

Comment: No, can you say more about it? Where that proxy should point? To my PC? I think that I could do the same using wireshark, without using HTTP Proxy

Comment: Yes, you could of course use wireshark to listen traffic, but I'm not that proficient with it to recommend it ;-) So, start Wireshark, run your HtmlUnit test, then perform the same authentication using your browser. Differences should be visible.

Comment: So how can I track requests using HTTP Proxy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117094/discussion-between-jakub-pomykala-and-riduidel).

Comment: @JakubPomykała, I know this is so old problem but maybe you can remember. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Sha I think a reCAPTCHA caught me and I couldn't go through.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did wrong was when you were looking for the "next" and the "sign in" buttons.

I'm pretty sure you need to do:
`List<HtmlInput> buttonInputs = loginForm.getInputsByName("signIn");`

Instead, you put
`List<HtmlInput> buttonInputs = loginForm.getInputsByValue("signIn");`

which isn't right because both the buttons have the same *name* of "signIn"
when the "next button" has a *value* of "Next" and the "sign in" button has a value of "Sign in".